# Adding differentials

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Suppose I have a sum of two Indefinite integrals, $\int f(t)dx + \int f(t)dy$. Is it possible to write this in a singke form as $\int f(t) d(x+y)$, and vise versa?

It looks “okay” to me from a logical point of view, but I obviously have no rigorous reasoning of why this should be

*Edit:*

I now realise that I might have stirred confusion by using a function of x. I have now changed **f** to a function of **t**. The reason I am asking is that I know that **x+y=t** so If i am able to express the differential in that form, integration would be possible

Comment: Please use MathJax to write formulas.
https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex
https://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: At peter foreman. I came across this situation in a physics question, where the sum of two integrals, int( 1/r^2 da) + int(1/r^2 db) was to be computed such that a+b=r. Oddly, the answer through the above method came out correct

Comment: If these are definite integrals, the second integral in the first expression would have an answer with $x$’s in the final expression while the second expression would not.

Comment: @Paul pls see the edit

Comment: @PeterForeman The integral isn’t being taken with respect to two variables.  The integral is being taken with respect to the sum of two variables.  The sum of two variables is a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that "d" is an *operator*, not a multiplier.  Think of $dx$ meaning $d(x)$ and being similar to $\sin(x)$.  So, if you had $f(x)\sin(x) + f(x)\sin(y)$ you could not rewrite that as $f(x)\sin(x + y)$.

That being said, as noted in the comments below, the addition rule states that $d(x + y) = d(x) + d(y)$, and this is true for both derivatives and differentials.

Therefore, let's do the requested transform a step at a time.  The starting formula:
$$
\int f(t)\,dx + \int f(t)\,dy
$$
We can use the addition rule to combine the integrals into one:
$$
\int \left(f(t)\,dx + f(t)\,dy\right)
$$
Now we can associate:
$$
\int f(t)(dx + dy)
$$
Now we can use the addition rule in differentials to combine the differentials together:
$$
\int f(t)\,d(x + y)
$$
And that is the result you were looking for.

NOTE - I had originally come out against this method based on the reasoning in the first paragraph, when someone pointed me to the obvious point about differentials and addition in the second paragraph.

Comment: True, but the derivative operator is distributive over addition. d(a+b)/dx is infsct equal to da/dx + db/dx

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH But it's **not** a derivative, it's a differential.

Comment: Actually, I think that @OVERWOOTCH may be right.  I'll have to think about it a little more, but the same rule applies to differentials, such that $d(a + b) = d(a) + d(b)$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Differentials are distributive over addition as well.

Answer (score 3):

Differentiation under integral sign is possible using Leibniz Integral Rule. However, it is not the same as keeping non-operating variables constant in a sort of "partial integration" mode. And these are not differentials.

I do not exactly get why you want to do this. If you want to include integration into a generality, then it is better to convert a constant into an extra variable. This part can be ignored if it is not addressing your concern/question.

If $x +i y =z $ then $ dx + i\; dy = dz .$ Combination with single complex variable is possible by contour integration etc., provided several accompanying complex operations are also adopted.

If you want more direction flexibility with integration, there should be more arguments for functional representation itself.

If p,V are variables with a product invariant $ T= p\cdot V $ we can unfreeze T giving it status of a variable $\dfrac{pV}{T}=R $. We can see that when T is constant, it is Boyle's law; if T is roped in as a new variable, $ pV/T = R $ where R is a more general universal gas constant. We can move more freely (extra dimension) on a surface rather than scramble on a narrow line.

Comment: can you explain the last part about scrambling on a line and stuff?

Comment: Trying to say there is more two dimensional  latitude on a surface $ z= f(x,y) $ rather than on a particular one dimensional contour lane $ g(x,y)= 0 $